# Creating multiple directories with mkdir and character range

Tags: bash, mkdir

My goal is to automate the creation of multiple directories that end with numerical indexes: `dir03 dir04 ... dir09`

I tried the following command: `mkdir dir0[3-9]`.

As the result, the shell created a directory named `dir0[3-9]`

I did try `mkdir dir0{3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. It works but it's less convenient.

What are the underlying reasons why `mkdir dir0[3-9]` doesn't work as intended?

Comment: `mkdir dir0{3..9}`? Dupes on the correct site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468500/542738, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48750/542738, ...

Comment: You should also consider reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515895/259023) by me.

Comment: `dir0[3-9]` is a globbing expression, and such is expanded to match existing directory entries. `dir0{3..9}` is an expression which **generates**  a list of arguments, without any reference to existing directory entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax a bit wrong:

- You used `[3-9]` as used in pattern matching for **matching an existing range** of values (a [range expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in [globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), used in filename expansion and a few other contexts, and also a [range expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Fundamental-Structure.html) in regular expressions).
- You need `{3..9}` as used in brace expansion for **generating a new range** of values (a [sequence expression](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)):

```
$ echo mkdir dir0{3..9}
mkdir dir03 dir04 dir05 dir06 dir07 dir08 dir09
```

remove the `echo` when happy with the output.

So we use `{3..9}` to **generate a new range** of values:

```
$ mkdir dir0{3..9}
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' {3..9}
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and `[3-9]` to **match an existing range** of values:

```
$ find . -name 'dir0[3-9]'
./dir03
./dir04
./dir05
./dir06
./dir07
./dir08
./dir09
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' {0..10} | grep '[3-9]'
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Note that they look similar but the semantics are different between range expressions in brace expansion and pattern matching, for example in brace expansion `{1..20}` expands to the numbers 1 through 20 (because ranges start/end with a potentially multi-digit number or a character) while in a range expression `[1-20]` expands to just the 3 numbers 1, 2, and 0 (because ranges always start/end with a character, not a string nor a multi-digit number, and so it means the set of the digits 1-2 and the digit 0).

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..20} | tr '\n' ' '
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$ printf '%s\n' {1..20} | grep '[1-20]' | tr '\n' ' '
1 2 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' {9..20} | tr '\n' ' '
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$ printf '%s\n' {9..20} | grep '[9-20]' | tr '\n' ' '
grep: Invalid range end
```

That last result is because the range in pattern matching always has to be increasing so `9-2` (the range before `0` in `[9-20]`) is invalid in a regexp:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {9..20} | grep '[2-9]' | tr '\n' ' '
9 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$ printf '%s\n' {9..20} | grep '[9-2]' | tr '\n' ' '
grep: Invalid range end
```

and in globbing:

```
$ ls -d dir0[2-9]
dir03  dir04  dir05  dir06  dir07  dir08  dir09

$ ls -d dir0[9-2]
ls: cannot access 'dir0[9-2]': No such file or directory
```

but is valid in brace expansion:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {2..9} | tr '\n' ' '
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

$ printf '%s\n' {9..2} | tr '\n' ' '
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Comment: @WeijunZhou updated, thanks.